# Python SQLModel - Optional ID value for auto-increment causes type errors when retrieving from database

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

If I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(DBModel, table=True):

    id: Optional[int] = Field( primary_key=True)
```

Then when saving new records to the database, the ID is automatically assigned, which is great.

However, when I retrieve the model like this I get type errors

```
model = session.get(MyModel, 1)
id: int = model.id  # ID may be None error
```

Is there a way to auto-assign my IDs but also have the ID type defined when retrieving saved records?

Comment: Do you get an actual id in the database?

Comment: Yes, the ID is assigned correctly. The issue is just with the typing. Any record which is retrieved from the database will have an ID but the type shows it as maybe being `None`.

Comment: That's not something you're going to be able to get around, since it _can_ be `None` (just not in your logic)

Comment: I know. It's easy enough to get around/ignore but it would be good to be able to differentiate between a pre-committed object and one which already exists in the DB.

I feel like there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Well how is your linter going to know if your session executes and updates the model correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You might find your answer here: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/multiple-models/#multiple-models-with-inheritance

Basically what you can do is define your models like this:

```
class MyModelBase(SQLModel):
    arg1: str
    ...


class MyModel(MyModelBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field( primary_key=True)


class MyModelRead(MyModelBase):
    id: int
```

Like that you are saying `MyModelRead` must have an attribute `id`. Note that only `MyModelBase` is a `SQLModel`. The other classes are `Pydantic` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when defining a field for id, you explicitly state the default value for ID like this

```
class MyModel(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
```

Because we don't set the id, it takes the Python's default value of `None` that we set in `Field(default=None)`

for more info read docs https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/automatic-id-none-refresh/